# Java Version upgrade for existing project from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: java, version, upgrade, java-5, jdk1.7

How do I upgrade an existing project running on JDK 1.5 to JDK 1.7? What type of compatibility issues I might have and how do I proceed, I'm blank on this.

Comment: Should be backwards compatible.

Comment: Aren't all JDKs backward compatible? AFAIK, you can compile 1.5 code on 1.7 without any issues. Some libraries etc. might have been marked deprecated but that's all.

Comment: They are backwards compatible, but there may be "quirks" depending on how well the Java itself is written. For example, lazily created Comparators that only return 1 or 0 rather than 1, 0, or -1 will no longer sort properly in 1.7 with the Sort being optimized in 1.7.

Comment: Why JDK 1.7 and not JDK 1.8? Note that JDK 1.7 has been [out-of-date](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html) for a while already.

Comment: If you have a good unit test coverage, unit test. Otherwise you can go through the change logs to see what may have affected your code. More often than not, the changes fix bugs but if you relied on such a bug your code will break.

Comment: See Oracle's official documentation about this here: [Java 7 Compatibility Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) and [Java 6 Compatibility Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html).

Comment: There are 2 questions here..1. How to upgrade 2. What kind of compatibility issues we get upgrading 1.5 to 1.7. Question 2 is already alnswered above. Regarding how to upgrade, it depends which IDE your using, changing the runtime JRE path, should be fine.

Comment: If there are configuration files specifying jdk version like pom.xml(maven), change the version there to 1.7

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I will look into every input provided by you all. Jesper, Thanks for the link, It's being very helpful, and I'm going to move to JDK 1.8 as 1.7 is already out of date. I'll get back here if there are any problems while doing the activity :)